# Problems with grabbing proper value of input on keydown/keyup

Tags: javascript, keyboard, jquery

I'm working on triggering events on certain key combinations that check the value of the input they were triggered in.

The problem I'm running into is that it's possible to trigger a `keypress` or a `keydown` AND type a character without triggering a `keyup`.

[image]

Conversely only the `keyup` event can read the value of the input with the newly inputted character because both the `keydown` and `keypress` fire before the character is added into the input.

[**JSFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/jnH5G/1/)

(**Note**: Press shift and any other character. If you hold shift and then press and release another character the `keyup` event will fire, but if you press and release shift at the same time as the other key, the `keyup` event will not fire.)

The only solutions I can think of are triggering the `keyup` event one the `keydown` event, but this can cause problems other places.

Unfortunately I also cannot just assume that because they pressed that key combination that the input field contains what I want, as they may enter the hotkey when there are other characters in the input.

Which leaves me with the thought that I would have to check the length of the input and if it equals zero and they just pressed that hotkey, that it would fire.

But I was wondering if there's a better way of doing this?

Comment: Still looking, but the problem appears to occur when the sequence is: SHIFT down, letter down, SHIFT up, letter up. This seems to reliably lose the KEYUP in Chrome, IE and FF. In FF, if the timing is tight, it sometimes also loses the KEYDOWN and only fires KEYPRESS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Keypress event seems to fire consistently. The problematic key-combinations fail to fire Keyup, but they DO fire an Input event (which, like Keyup, comes after the input value has changed). Input, however, doesn't carry information about the actual keystroke.

I don't know what conditions you're actually looking for with regards to the contents of the input. But listening for Keypress and then getting the new input contents upon the next Input event sounds like it may be what you need.

Something like:

```
var hotkey = false;
var lastChar = '';

$('#in').on('keypress', function(e) {
    hotkey = ((e.which > 16 || e.which < 16) && e.shiftKey);
    lastChar = e.which;    
});


$('#in').on('input', function(e) {
    if (hotkey)
        $("#out").append('<div>' + lastChar + ' + shiftKey triggered ' + '<br/> INPUT: ' + $("#in").val() + '</div>');
});
```

Comment: Nice workaround. I didn't even know about the `input` event. Turns out I can just use that and check the input length and determine if the proper character exists in the input. Thanks.

Comment: I found it in the process of trying to answer the question, actually, which is handy - it proved useful on my own project today.